# Why is my .class file bigger when I change my int array to a char array?

Tags: java, memory

So I have a line of code in my file, that reads

```
char[] arr = new char[256];
```

However, when I change this to

```
int[] arr = new int[256];
```

the class file shrinks by .01 Kb. Why is this?

Comment: Why don't you do a `diff` (`FC /B` in Windows) on the files to see what's different?

Answer (score 4):

Its probably because the compiler generates a symbol that is a few characters shorter. Just like in the `.java` file the first line will create a bigger file because it has more characters.

If you open the `.class` in vim you will see the following for an `int` array.

```
Êþº¾^@^@^@2^@^O
^@^C^@^L^G^@^M^G^@^N^A^@^F<init>^A^@^C()V^A^@^DCode^A^@^OLineNumberTable^A^@^Dmain^A^@^V([Ljava/lang/String;)V^A^@
SourceFile^A^@!JFileChooserDisableDirectory.java^L^@^D^@^E^A^@^\JFileChooserDisableDirectory^A^@^Pjava/lang/Object^@!^@^B^@^C^@^@^@^@^@^B^@^A^@^D^@^E^@^A^@^F^@^@^@^]^@^A^@^A^@^@^@^E*·^@^A±^@^@^@^A^@^G^@^@^@^F^@^A^@^@^@^A^@  ^@^H^@  ^@^A^@^F^@^@^@"^@^A^@^B^@^@^@^F^P
¼
L±^@^@^@^A^@^G^@^@^@
^@^B^@^@^@^D^@^E^@^E^@^A^@
^@^@^@^B^@^K
```

Here is the `char` array `.class` file.

```
Êþº¾^@^@^@2^@^O
^@^C^@^L^G^@^M^G^@^N^A^@^F<init>^A^@^C()V^A^@^DCode^A^@^OLineNumberTable^A^@^Dmain^A^@^V([Ljava/lang/String;)V^A^@
SourceFile^A^@!JFileChooserDisableDirectory.java^L^@^D^@^E^A^@^\JFileChooserDisableDirectory^A^@^Pjava/lang/Object^@!^@^B^@^C^@^@^@^@^@^B^@^A^@^D^@^E^@^A^@^F^@^@^@^]^@^A^@^A^@^@^@^E*·^@^A±^@^@^@^A^@^G^@^@^@^F^@^A^@^@^@^A^@  ^@^H^@  ^@^A^@^F^@^@^@"^@^A^@^B^@^@^@^F^P
¼^EL±^@^@^@^A^@^G^@^@^@
^@^B^@^@^@^D^@^E^@^E^@^A^@
^@^@^@^B^@^K
```

Using [TextDiff](http://textdiff.com) you can see the differences in the code.

Comment: Interesting! For memory conservation purposes, would it still be worth using a char array instead of an int array? Intuition would say yes, but I'm not sure anymore.

Comment: If you want to conserve memory, you probably want a `short[]` or `byte[]`. Java chars are 2-byte unsigned integers, which probably isn't what you want.

Comment: It wouldn't make a noticeable difference. Even if you had a million arrays it would still only be a mb or so.

Comment: *"For memory conservation purposes, would it still be worth using a char array instead of an int array?"* - What gives you the idea that you can infer the size of a character array from the size of the ".class" file?  They are totally unrelated issues!

Comment: @StephenC I mis-interpreted his question, good point you got there.

Comment: @DummyCode - I don't think you misinterpreted the Question at all.  The OP didn't tell us *why* he thought the code size was significant until the comment above.

Comment: The reason I'm being so massively nitpicky is because the byte code has to clock in at under 4kb. It's for a Java 4k competition, and I've never had to worry about such tiny things to make it smaller, so I'm still a bit iffy about the best way to go about it.

Comment: @user1522860 Whatever makes the code run faster, this is too small to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

Probably just because the symbol for the type is a tad bit shorter.

Comment: You'd think so, but if I change the "char" to "short", it also shrinks in size.

Comment: @user1522860 - for the same reason.  If you really want / need to understand, you will need to manually decode the class files yourself ... using the class file format as specified in the JVM spec.  But, the answer is of no consequence ... so don't expect people to waste their time doing it for you.